# Emulate url on file XML

Tags: php, xml

(Apache+PHP+ZF 1.12) I want do create url like http://domain.loc/docs/example.xml . But file `example.xml` doesn`t exists. It will create "online" : emulating that it exists.

```
 <?php        
    // generate example.xml
    // ...
    <?php header("Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8"); ?>
    echo $example_content_xml;
    die;
 ?>
```

User go to http://domain.loc/docs/example.xml. Then script run and output `example.xml`.

**EDIT**

Question: how run script by url http://domain.loc/docs/example.xml and this work only folder http://domain.loc/docs/.

Comment: OK, but  what is your question?

Comment: Indeed, that's what you have to do, where are you stuck?

Comment: @Pekka By http://domain.loc/docs/example.xml ->  run script.

Comment: I can't quickly find a perfectly matching example but you want to look into Apache's `mod_rewrite` which can accept any URL and redirect it internally to your PHP script.

Comment: Add an `.htaccess` file in that subfolder (`/docs/`) and rewrite any request to a script file such as `/docs/script.php`. This is fairly easy using apache mod_rewrite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Apache's mod_rewrite module. Create a file named .htaccess with the following content:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^docs/example.xml example.php [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Sorry,this is a little something. You redirect to example.php.

Comment: I'm not redirecting. The URL will remain as http://www.example.com/docs/example.xml; the only thing that changes is that its contents will be loaded from example.php (executed by server).